# both anonymous and logged-in users can view everything on my plone site

Tags: plone

We are using Plone 4.1.   Don't know why but both anonymous and logged-in users can view all the pages of our site.

Can anybody advise?

Thank you

cmgui

Comment: Perhaps a bit more info will help someone answer here also. For instance, did you customize the site at all? How are you using it. What permissions and workflow do you have setup. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons anonymous and logged in users can view all the pages on your site

1. Everything on the site is public
2. You could have the community workflow set as the default workflow
3. You could have no workflow set as the default workflow.
4. You have used the sharing button on the site to give view permission to anonymous users.
5. Maybe someone messed with the site permissions in the ZMI

You need to look at the workflow and permission setting you have set on the site--that will tell you why things are visible or not. If you're not aware of how workflows work, you can always read the documentation http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/collaboration-and-workflow

Comment: 4. should not grant rights to Anonymous User. (Undocumented freak bug: don't ever call yourself 'Anonymous User'.)

Comment: Thank you Vangheem and Ulrich

Comment: Thank you Vangheem and Ulrich.  I tried changing the community workflow settings as per the instructions here: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/make-folder-hierarchy-private    But no effect as our site default workflow (Types in the Control Panel) is Simple Publication Workflow.   When I tried to change from Simple Publication Workflow to Community Workflow or any other workflow, I got this error: Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish

Comment: Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.controlpanel.types, line 165, in __call__
  Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 583, in subscribers

Comment: Module zope.interface.adapter, line 583, in subscribers
  Module plone.app.discussion.browser.controlpanel, line 181, in notify_configuration_changed
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'forInterface'

Comment: Thank you Ulrich.  I didn't assign any rights to Anonymous user.   I now understand that by default, plone uses the Simple Publication Workflow and when we publish something, everybody including anonymous user (not logged in ) can view it.   This is not what we want.  I tried to change from Simple Publication Workflow to Intranet Workflow, but got error (see above).   Also tried the suggestion here: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/make-folder-hierarchy-private.   But no use because cannot change to Community Workflow -- got the same error.

Comment: It sounds like you want an intranet workflow, not a community workflow. A community workflow would make everything private by default.

Comment: Also, if the types control panel is broken in the version of plone you're using, you can accomplish the same thing by going to /manage -> portal_workflow. Then setting the default type to something other than "simple_publication_workflow". Click the contents tab to see the different options. Then click the update security button to apply the workflow to existing object. Be careful what you do in the ZMI though!

Comment: Thank you Vangheem for the suggestion of using zope to change the workflow type.     I got what I want now.